# Why does Relay need a mutation id to reconcile GraphQL mutations?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I've tried to figure out why, but always end up concluding that the "tracking" could be easily done within the closure of the request that was sent. I'm clearly missing something here.

Why does Relay need a mutation ID to track the request/response?

Comment: Have you seen https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/mutations.htm? It's not an answer to your question but the best resource I could find :)

Comment: @marktani, I have. Thanks for the link though. :)

Answer (score 1):

> "tracking" could be easily done within the closure of the request that was sent

You're thinking in terms of implementation. Relay is a JavaScript framework that implements the Relay specification. Under the specification, it is not a good idea to rely on something (closure) that a language may or may not support. Therefore, [Relay Input Object Mutations Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/mutations.htm) specifies `clientMutationId` to track the mutation.

Comment: I see. I've read the spec before but hadn't thought of that. Would you mind giving an example of a language where something like JS closures won't be available to track mutations?

Comment: My C++ knowledge is rusty. AFAIK, C++ before C++11 standard does not have built-in closure support.